Prove that the function $f(x,y,z)=1+x^2+y^2+z^2+2xyz-2xy-2xz-2yz$ is strictly positive outside of some bounded set.
Consider the function $$f(x,y,z)=1+x^2+y^2+z^2+2xyz-2xy-2xz-2yz,$$ where $x,y,z\geq 0$.
Prove that there exists a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f\geq \frac{1}{2}$ outside of this set.
Note that it is possible to prove that the function is in fact non-negative everywhere. However, I am not interested in that proof, and more interested in the techniques that provide a lower bound on this function outside of a large enough bounded set.

NO.  If $x=y=z=t$  the function is $1 - 3t^2  + 2t^3 $

@WillJagy- How is that a contradiction? Clearly outside of a bounded set (hence if $t$ is large enough), the function is $\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Nothing you posted suggests that my $t$   needs to be positive.

@RyanHendricks If the set is bounded, so for some $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ you get that for all $t\le t_0$ $f(t,t,t)$ is outside the bounded set, meaning $\lim\limits_{t\to -\infty} f(t,t,t)$ is outside the bounded set but it is not satisfying $f\ge \frac 12$ because $\lim\limits_{t\to -\infty} f(t,t,t)=-\infty$

@WillJagy- Apologies for the omission, I have now added that $x,y,z\geq 0$.

@Afield- Sorry, I have now added that $x,y,z\geq 0$.

prolly something like this is useful: let $(x,y,z) = t(n_x,n_y,n_z): |(n_x,n_y,n_z)| = 1$ and since at $t = 0,+\infty$ your $f>0$ look for the point where the cubic w.r.t $t$ starts to be nonnegative always (for fixed $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$). Then if set of critical points $S = {t_{critical}(n_x,n_y,n_z)}$ is bounded possibly and thus vectors of of length $sup(S)+1$ will be positive

One desired bounded set is  $\boxed{ S := \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \ | \ 0 \le x,y,z \le 100 \} }$. We'll show that outside of this bounded set, we have $f(x,y,z) \ge 1/2$.
Proving $f(x,y,z) \ge 0$ is actually a famous inequality. The simplest solution to that uses the fact that $f$ can be written in the form $$f(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2 + 2x(y-1)(z-1) + (y-z)^2.$$ Similarly, the other two forms are
$\begin{align}
f(x,y,z) &= (y-1)^2 + 2y(x-1)(z-1) + (x-z)^2 \\
&= (z-1)^2 + 2z(x-1)(y-1) + (x-y)^2 . \\
\end{align}$
For $f(x,y,z) \ge 0$, it suffices to notice that at least two of $x,y,z$ has to lie at the same side of $1$ (either both $\ge1$, or both $<1$), by pigeonhole principle. Using the corresponding form among the three forms mentioned above then proves $f(x,y,z) \ge 0$, as all three terms in the sum become $\ge 0$.
However, we want to prove something slightly different, i.e., $$f(x,y,z) \ge 1/2 \quad \forall (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}^3 \setminus S.$$ To prove it, let us assume the contrary, that $$\exists (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}^3 \setminus S \quad \text{such that} \quad f(x,y,z) < 1/2.$$ Let $(x',y',z')$ be a triple that satisfies $(x',y',z') \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}^3 \setminus S\ $, and for which we have $1/2 > f(x',y',z')$.
Note that $(x',y',z') \notin S$ means that, among $x',y',z'$ there is at least one that is greater than $100$. We keep this in mind.
Similarly to the previous proof (of $\ge0$), without loss of generality assume that $y'$ and $z'$ lie at the same side of $1$, that is, either $y',z'\ge1$ or $y',z' < 1$.
We have
$\begin{align}
1/2 &> (x'-1)^2 + \underbrace{2x'(y'-1)(z'-1)}_{\ge0} + \underbrace{(y'-z')^2}_{\ge0} \\
&\ge (x'-1)^2,
\end{align}$
therefore $1/2 > (x'-1)^2$, or equivalently, $ \boxed{ 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \le x' \le 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} } $. In particular, this means $x'\le100$. Therefore, at least one of $y',z'$ must be greater than $100$ (as we know that at least one of $x',y',z'$ is). Without loss of generality, assume $\boxed{ y' > 100 }$.
Now we analyze two cases for $z'$.
Case 1: $z'<99$
This case results in a contradiction as it implies $(y'-z')^2 > 1$ due to $y'>100$, which then gives
$\begin{align}
1/2 &> \underbrace{(x'-1)^2}_{\ge0} + \underbrace{2x'(y'-1)(z'-1)}_{\ge0} + \underbrace{(y'-z')^2}_{>1} \\
&> 1
\end{align}$
which is a contradiction.
Case 2: $z'\ge99$
This case gives a contradiction too, by
$\begin{align}
1/2 &> \underbrace{(x'-1)^2}_{\ge0} \ + \ 2 \cdot \underbrace{x'}_{\ge 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}} \cdot \underbrace{(y'-1)}_{\ge99} \cdot \underbrace{(z'-1)}_{\ge98} \ + \ \underbrace{(y'-z')^2}_{\ge0} \\
&\ge (1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}) \cdot 99 \cdot 98 \\
&>1000
\end{align}$
which is a contradiction again.
As a result, our assumption to the contrary was wrong, and therefore $$\boxed{f(x,y,z) \ge 1/2 \quad \forall (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}^3 \setminus S}. \quad \blacksquare$$

Thanks! You mention that it is a famous inequality. Can I get a reference for it?

I don't think there's a well-known name it is being referred to as. I just saw a page or two in AoPS where they call it "Estonia 2018 inequality", but it is quite famous in AoPS without a name. It actually is weaker than Schur's ineuqality for $t=1$. This is because when you apply $AM-GM$ to 2abc+1, it simplifies to Schur for $t=1$.
